# Is there a way to remove the white space just before an integer in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to remove the white space from certain strings only in the 'Player' column that contains a white space just before the integer. Here's a reference image.

[image: Dataframe]

For example, I need the output for 1040 to be 'Joshua Kimmich24, D(CR),DMC'

The first five objects in the 'Player' column can also be used as a reference, they are correct in their format, they need to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression replacement:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\s+(\d)') # matches whitespace followed by number, captures the number
df['Player'] = [regex.sub(r'\1', player ) for player in df['Player']]
```